# Django Admin: How to Override Add Form to Choose Existing Object Instead of Raising 'Already Exists' Error?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working with Django and using the Django admin panel for managing a model called Keyword. When adding a new instance of the Keyword model, I want to customize the behavior so that if the keyword already exists, the admin form should select the existing keyword instead of raising the 'Already Exists' error.

[When i try to add keyword that already exists it wont let me so i have to scroll thru hundreds of keywords to find the one i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpcvj.png)

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1YmG.png)

I have attempted various approaches, including custom forms and overriding the save_model method in the admin class, but the issue persists. The current implementation still raises a "Keyword with this Name already exists" error.

Edit: here is models.py code

```py
from django.db import models
  class Keyword(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
     def __str__(self):
         return self.name
  class Meme(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)
     audio = models.FileField(upload_to='audio/')
     def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

Comment: Share your current `ModelAdmin`.

Comment: It's empty, i changed some things, then reverted back because it was not working. whole admin file just have 2 admin.site.register for models and thats it

Comment: yes - share those two sites

Comment: in order to have `keyword` show up in the admin panel you *have* to have made a class that uses `admin.ModelAdmin` - so something like `KeywordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)` or similar. This is what tells Django how it should show `keyword ` in the admin interface. please share this. also Do not paste code in the comments - edit your question to include the code in it.

Comment: understood, thank you, but keywords is already showing up in admin just fine, what i want is when i try to add keyword to my second model , i can add as many keywords i want but if keyword is already added i have to scroll thru thousands of keywords to find keyword that i want, so i want to do it like this, when i try to add new keyword but it already exists, i want it to just choose that keyword.

Comment: in order to understand why you are getting that error we need to see how you have defined the admin pages for `keyword` and `meme` - so please share the admin.py (or wherever you have placed them) as well.

Comment: Note: This question is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), the duplicate I've linked solves problem X and not problem Y. If you feel that is not suitable and actually do want to solve problem Y, feel free to reply to this comment and I'll reopen this question.